# Non-serializable File object in Redux action

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I currently have a Redux action that looks like this:

```js
{
  type: 'user/updateRequested',
  payload: {name: 'Foo', avatar: File}
}
```

that File is not serializable so I'm wondering if there's a better way.

When the action is dispatched, three things happen:

- A reducer updates the `state.user.name` but ignores `avatar`
- A Saga uploads the file to the API
- A Saga uses a FileReader to get a Data URL and dispatch another action (which causes `state.user.avatar` to be updated)

I'm never storing the File object in the store, it's only in actions.

**Is there a better way or is this a use case where non-serializable actions are valid?**

Comment: I use the same approach so I think is fine (because did not find a better solution).

Comment: Just out of interest, are you performing any compression on the file?

Comment: @MattSugden No, it's straight from an `<input>` - `myInput.files[0]` sagas read/upload that file from the action

Comment: I was asking as I've just done something similar, and when taking a picture on an iPhone the image is around 4MB, which is a lot to be uploading and downloading.

Answer (score 3):

The file is serializable in theory (base64 for example) but it would probably make using the devtools harder or cause other unexpected side effects with that much data.

I agree that it's valid to not store the actual file content in action payloads.

You could save a hash of the file (or simply the name and a timestamp) and use this as a key to access the file in another type of storage if it becomes necessary to have the content. This would make time travel work again, but only if the actions are replayed in the same environment where the file content can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

```js
export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
   \\Put your reducers here
  },
  middleware:getDefaultMiddleware({
    \\this way you don't remove the middlewares
    serializableCheck:false,
  }),
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue.
This is how had configured my store.

```
export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
      vehicles: vehicleReducer,
    },
    middleware: [...getDefaultMiddleware(), apiMiddleware],
});
```

Once I got rid of `getDefaultMiddleware`, the error was gone for me.

Comment: This will indeed remove the warnings and errors from the log. But, it's just ignoring the problem. By removing the default middlewares, you are removing thunk middleware, or, in production, immutableCheck and serializableCheck middlewares as well. These two check the data going into redux actions and state. By removing serializableCheck middleware, the warnings and errors go away.